# How to copy Minecraft PE worlds using iExplorer, encountering "Value cannot be null"?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In order to copy my minecraft worlds from an Apple device, or to support wiping the iDevice on which these worlds are stored, I've followed the process in [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/251382/148546).

However, as I'm moving the files back to the iPad I get a message saying: "value cannont be null. parameter name: source" and then the files in the folders are not transferring.  Any suggestions?

---

Comment: Welcome to gaming stackexchange. Have you read about how to ask [quality questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?  It is good academic practice to avoid plagiarism: when you want to include existing content, credit the author, or provide a link where the reader can find out who wrote it.  Only include the relevant part with a quote if you do not need everything. If you do, why not just add a link?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this specifically with *iExplorer*, you will have to contact **[macroplant](https://macroplant.com/support)** and obtain support. The program appears to have encountered some sort of error and bugged out. The message you see appears when a C# application attempts to access an object that doesn't exist.

It's basically the equivalent of a null pointer dereference, or `sigsegv` in plain C. Figuring out what caused it in a locked-down closed-source obfuscated commercial application (which is what iExplorer appears to be) is basically *not worth the effort*. Especially since, it turns out, the files you were trying to transfer are simply available to the user on the iDevice. There's no need to use this application.

I've written an answer to the [existing question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/373166/148546) about the topic on how to copy without using *iExplorer*.