# Restoring Minecraft PE world

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My daughter had a Minecraft PE world saved in the Files app on an iPad. How can she restore it to a fresh reinstallation of Minecraft after the game was uninstalled? Note that she could not sign in to Microsoft and had to create a new account.

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/238485/163757

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

If the backup is saved in the Files app, try this:

You will need...
The apple device (Duh)
A computer with iTunes installed
A data-transfer cable (The one that came with the device will work)

1. Plug the device into the computer and open iTunes
2. Click the phone/tablet icon that appears in the upper left of the screen. It may take a few minutes to show up
3. Select "File Sharing" from the left-hand menu
4. Select "Minecraft", select the "games" folder and select "Save File" (You may also want to backup this folder just in case something goes wrong)
5. Select "Files", then locate the backup folder and save it as well.
6. Using the file explorer on the computer, copy the backup folder into the "minecraftWorlds" folder (Located within the "games" folder you downloaded.)
7. Back in iTunes, select "Minecraft" again, then "Add File", upload the modified "games" folder containing the new backup.
8. Eject the device and test.